# What is the etymology of the word 'afforestation'?

Tags: etymology

I can get the definition of 'afforestation' from Google, but not how this word was created in the first place. Also, the affix is not clear to me.

Does anyone know anything about it? Please explain it to me.

Comment: Wiktionary gives the etymology (partly via links).

Answer (score 1):

Well, [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/afforestation) says:

> Medieval Latin *afforestation-, afforestatio,* from *afforestare* to put
>   under forest laws, from Latin *ad-* + Medieval Latin *foresta, forestis*
>   forest
>
> First Known Use: 1649

(Which is interesting — I would have guessed that it was a neologism.)

Answer (score 0):

The root word here is *forest.* The verb *afforest* means to create a forest (the prefix *af-* actually comes from *ad-* in Latin, meaning "to, onto"). The *-ion* suffix for a noun is obvious.

(Don't thank me, I got most of this from Merriam-Webster, actually).